# Talking to C++ library with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-c++, coin-or-cbc

I have a node.js Express web application and I need to talk to this optimization library named CBC from COIN-OR:

https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc

what is the best way to talk to this library using node.js? could I create a node.js wrapper around the C++ library or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about performance, then writing an [addon](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html) (and/or possibly using [`nan`](https://github.com/rvagg/nan/) to let the addon work across major node.js/io.js versions) that wraps the library is the best solution.

If taking a considerable performance hit is *not* a concern, you could use [`ffi`](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) to call "directly" to the library from javascript.

Comment: seems like best way to give back to community is to write the addon, right